# Get windows session's user name in c++

Tags: windows, session, terminal-services

I am trying to understand better how Windows sessions (TS sessions and log on sessions) works (currently in XP), so maybe my whole question or what I am trying to do is impossible.

I am running a Windows service (in XP), which runs in session 0, and I am trying to get the username attached to this session using `WTSQueryUserToken()`.
Now, in session 0 there are several usernames: `SYSTEM`, `theuser` (logged on user),`NETWORK SERVICE`, `LOCAL SERVICE`.

When I use `WTSQueryUserToken()` I get "theuser" (which is the Active session), but I am trying to get the username of my service (which is SYSTEM).
Is that possible or did I simply get it all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code to get user token for my process

```
HANDLE GetProcessOwnerToken(DWORD pid)
{
    if (!pid) return NULL;

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    if (!hProcess) return NULL;

    HANDLE hToken = NULL;
    if(OpenProcessToken(hProcess, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, &hToken))
    {
        HANDLE result = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        if(DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &result))
        {
            if(result != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                CloseHandle(hToken);
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
                return result;
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }
    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return NULL;
}
```

I have no idea if it works for services as well, I think it should.

Comment: That worked - Thanks! :-)
So a session has nothing to do with the username, but the process token?!

Comment: You're welcome :-) Token represents a process's security context and it contains information about associated logon session and user id. You have to work with tokens, not usernames. The term 'session' in Windows is a little bit confusing comparing with Linux for example. Also please remember that in Vista and later services work in Session 0 and user desktop in Session 1 and service can't interact with desktop.